# Wordpress Most Commented Articles in The Past Month

Tags: php, wordpress, while-loop

I have read all the articles on this subject.I don't want to do this by creating a function.Therefore the articles I read did not help me.

In theory with this code, we need to list the articles of the last month that received the most comments.

```
$month = date('m', strtotime(date('Y-m-d') . " -1 month"));
$year = date('Y');
echo $month;
echo $year;
$args = array(
  'posts_per_page' => 5,
  'year'     => $year,
  'monthnum' => $month,
  'orderby' => 'comment_count',
  'order' => 'DESC'
);
$posts = new WP_Query($args);

while ($posts->have_posts()) : $posts->the_post();
  the_title();
endwhile; wp_reset_query();
```

The query I am trying to do is like this.I think this query is correct.But there is no result.I couldn't find out which part I made a mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'posts_per_page' => 5,
    'orderby' => 'comment_count',
    'order' => 'desc',
    'date_query' => array(
        array(
            'before' => '1 month ago',
        ),
    ),
);
```

Comment: Thank you for answering.But again, there is no result.

Comment: @Check78 Let me check above code in one of the my server website.

Comment: @Check78 I have updated code as well as tested it. It's working fine. So please check it and Let me know.

Comment: Finds results with this code.But in those older than a month, it appears on the list.

Comment: Please note that code-only answers are discouraged on StackOverflow. Please add an explanation of what this code is doing and how it will fix the issue, so that it helpful to other users with similar issues.